# Angular momentum ladder operators seems to require $-1/\sqrt{2}$ factor to produce states with amplitude 1 in the Hydrogen atom $(2,1,m)$ states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I have done an exercise consisting to check how the ladder operators produce the expected states once they are applied to some initial state and I have obtained an unexpected result, the amplitude for the resulting state is $-\sqrt{2}$, instead of 1 as I would expect. I have used for this test the Hydrogen atom $(2,1,m)$ states: $(2,1,-1)$, $(2,1,0)$ and $(2,1,1)$ whose wave functions can be found here:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html

To recap, the ladder operators for the Z-axis are:
$$L_{+} = L_{x} + i*L_{y}$$
$$L_{-} = L_{x} - i*L_{y}$$

My approach is this: I take one Z-state, for example, $(2,1,1)$, and I project it against the X and Y states, getting  some amplitudes:
$$\psi _{211z} \rightarrow  c_{1}\psi _{21-1x}+c_{2}\psi _{210x}+c_{3}\psi _{211x}$$

Where the amplitudes would be the projection of the current state $\psi _{211z}$ against the X-states and Y-states, for example,  $c_{1}= <\psi _{21-1x}|\psi _{211z}>$.

The $L_{x}$ operator will work on the X-states by multiplying them by the value of m, $(2,1,-1)$ by -1, $(2,1,0)$ by 0 (thus, destroying it), and $(2,1,1)$ by 1. The $L_{y}$ operator would work similarly over the Y-states.

Once we have the result of $L_{+}|\psi _{211z}>$ expressed in X-states and Y-states, I project them back to my target Z-state $<\psi _{21mz}$ by using $<\psi _{21mz}|\psi _{21\pm x}>$ and $<\psi _{21mz}|\psi _{21\pm y}>$. It is expected that only one state will have an amplitude of 1 and the other two states will have zero amplitude, except in the cases of $L_{+}|\psi _{211z}>$ and $L_{-}|\psi _{21-1z}>$ in which all the target states will have zero amplitude since we are using the ladder operators outside the scope of $l$. Of course for the $(2,1,1)$ state, the target state with non zero probability for $L_{-}$ is $(2,1,0)$

The amplitudes for all these projections can be calculated with a script, for example with Matlab. It is enough to integrate over the polar coordinates since all these states share the same radial function. After running the scripts, I have got the following amplitudes between the Z-states and the X and Y-states:

|  | (2,1,0,z) | (2,1,1,z) | (2,1,-1,z) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (2,1,0,x) | 0 | $1/\sqrt(2)$ | $1/\sqrt(2)$ |
| (2,1,0,y) | 0 | $i/\sqrt(2)$ | $-i/\sqrt(2)$ |
| (2,1,1,x) | $-1/\sqrt(2)$ | 0.5 | -0.5 |
| (2,1,1,y) | $i/\sqrt(2)$ | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| (2,1,-1,x) | $-1/\sqrt(2)$ | -0.5 | 0.5 |
| (2,1,-1,y) | $-i/\sqrt(2)$ | 0.5 | 0.5 |

With these amplitudes the results that I have got are:

$$L_{-}|\psi _{211z}> = -\sqrt{2} \psi _{210z}$$
$$L_{+}|\psi _{210z}> = -\sqrt{2} \psi _{211z}$$

This would suggest that the ladder operators would need to be multiplied by a factor:
$$L_{+} = -(1/\sqrt{2})(L_{x} + i*L_{y})$$
$$L_{-} = -(1/\sqrt{2})(L_{x} - i*L_{y})$$

Is something incorrect in my calculations? Otherwise why is this factor not included in the ladder operators?

Comment: The factors of $\sqrt{2}$ are entirely correct.  It's not clear why you need all this stuff about $L_x$ etc.  Is this a chemistry question?  At any rate, if the $\psi_{211;z}$ state is $R_{21}(r)Y_1^{1}(\theta,\varphi)$ then it's the same radial part and the action of $L_-$ on $Y_1^{1}(\theta,\varphi)$ is $\sqrt{2}Y_1^{0}(\theta,\varphi)$.  The only source of error would be in converting between your bases but then again... Why do you need to do this if you want the action of $\hat L_\pm$ in the $z$-basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition
$$
L_+ = L_x + i L_y,\quad L_- = L_x - iL_y
$$
does not need to be corrected. It is known that if $|l,m\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the operators $L^2$ and $L_z$ with eigenvalues $\hbar l(l+1)$ and $\hbar m$, then
$$
L_+ |l,m\rangle = \hbar \sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m+1)}\ |l,m+1\rangle,
$$
$$
L_- |l,m\rangle = \hbar \sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m-1)}\ |l,m-1\rangle.
$$
For $l = 1$, $m = 0$ we get
$$
L_+|1,0\rangle = \hbar\sqrt{2}\ |1,1\rangle
$$
So your calculation is probably correct. The difference in the minus sign is insignificant; it can be compensated by defining the eigenvectors.

You can find a discussion of this topic in books on quantum mechanics. In particular, this question is considered in the books “Quantum Mechanics: A graduate level course” by R. Fitzpatrick and "Modern Quantum Mechanics" by J.J. Sakurai and J. Napolitano.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but $L_\pm = L_x\pm i L_y$ is correct.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Of course this is correct. Such a definition can hardly be wrong. We take it and derive consequences. I tried to explain that the OP's extensive calculations produced the expected result. My interpretation of the question is whether the $L_{\pm}$ operators should be redefined so that their action on normalized states produces normalized states. It is clear from my answer that this is impossible. I assume that Sergio Prats is studying quantum theory on his own and is simply unfamiliar with this part of the knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for bringing the definition of $L_{+}|l,m> for any value of l and m and for references to this topic in books.